# why is a pointer function always have void return type?

Tags: c

I have seen many programs with pointer functions that have the `void` return type. What is the reason behind this? What is the actual need of a `void` pointer function?

```
void *print_message_function( void *ptr ){
    int *message,i,j;
    message = (int *) ptr;
    if(*message == 1){
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){ res1 += array[i];
        }
    }

    else if(*message == 2){
        for(i=5;i<10;i++){
            res2 += array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

If possible, please give a real life example of when you'd use a `void` pointer function.

Comment: The OP's example is missing a `return <address>;` statement.

Comment: @alk: or is not meant to return a value at all and should just be typed `void` instead of `void *`.

Comment: @JohnBode From what the question is about, I doubt this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function pointer can have pretty much any return type. Consider this example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// this defines a type called MathOp that is a function pointer returning
// an int, that takes 2 int arguments
typedef int (*MathOp)(int, int);

enum MathOpType
{
    Add = 1,
    Subtract = 2
};

// some generic math operation to add two numbers
int AddOperation(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

// some generic math operation to subtract two numbers
int SubtractOperation(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}

// function to return a math operation function pointer based on some argument
MathOp GetAMathOp(MathOpType opType)
{
    if (opType == MathOpType::Add)
        return &AddOperation;

    if (opType == MathOpType::Subtract)
        return &SubtractOperation;

    return NULL;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // declare a variable with the type MathOp, which is a function pointer to
    // a function taking two int arguments, and returning an int.
    MathOp op = &AddOperation;
    std::cout << op(2, 3) << std::endl;

    // switch the operation we want to perform by calling our one op variable
    op = &SubtractOperation;
    std::cout << op(2, 3) << std::endl;

    // just an example of using a function that returns a function pointer
    std::cout << GetAMathOp(MathOpType::Subtract)(5, 1) << std::endl;

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The program above prints 5, -1, and then 4. Function pointers can have any return type, and  are very powerful.

Comment: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) what is _TCHAR*?

Comment: i did this in VS2010 as a console app. that's just how Visual Studio defines int main() for windows console apps. Don't really worry about that definition, worry about the other code that i've written. But to answer the TCHAR question, it's just a definition for a string that translates to a Unicode char array in Unicode builds, and a regular char array in non-unicode builds

Answer (score 3):

Your terminology of "pointer function" is confusing.  It seems to me that your question is

> Of all functions that return a pointer to some type, it appears that
>   very many of them are functions that return a pointer to void. 
>   Is there any reason for that?

If that is indeed your question, then -- Yes, in C, a `void *` can be converted to `AnyOtherType *` without requiring a cast.  As a result, functions such as **qsort** that take a pointer to a function ("callbacks" as another poster alluded to), can serve as a "generic" function.  When sorting values of a particular type, you pass your own comparator function which internally knows that it is really not a `void *`, but `YourOwnType *`.

Comment: +1: I have no idea why the other answers talk about function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

A function pointer can have any return type, it is just a pointer to a function, so if a function does not intend to anything it returns a `void` and so does the function pointer.

The most common usage of function pointers is in implementing **callbacks** to provide an asynchronous mechanism.

An previous answer of mine, explains this in much detail:

**[Callback functions in C/C++/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184236/452307)**

Comment: According to your code on above link  what is callback_map[event] = function; ?is it array or key value pair mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for a function pointer to return a void type.  90% of the examples demonstrate function pointers with void types; because, it is less information (and hopefully less confusion) to distract the reader from the focus of the pointer to the function.

[This excellent tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) clearly demonstrates function pointers to functions that return an `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define a pointer function? If you mean to say "pointer to a function", it's clearly not that. Instead it is returning a void pointer. The advantage of using void pointer is that it is generic in nature and can be converted to the pointer of our requirement.